# Specify unique value (constant) for mysql field

Tags: mysql

I'd like to make a field unique in mysql **but only for a certain value**.

So, saying I have **flag** being an int I want there to only exist a flag = 3 where *something something* but there should exist other flags with the same value instead of 3 (like many *2*, *1*,etc) so it is only unique to 3... is this possible? Thank you very much. (Language is PHP)

Comment: This is usually solved with a partial unique index - but MySQL does not support this. You need a trigger for this in MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how should this trigger be done? `on insert`? and how can I do a trigger that depends on other fields? (flag = 3 must happen once per `par` of fields - for example, flag = 3 where first = 2 and second = 3. If first = 2 and second = 3 in another field then flag can't be = 3 there... I hope I made my point...